# My function won't return the proper value

Tags: lua, prime-factoring

I am currently doing problem 3 on project Euler and I have run into a problem while writing a function that returns the max prime factor of a number.

I made two functions, isprime(number) and maxprime(number). The first function works just fine, returning true if a number is prime, but the ladder function gives me the problem.

```lua
function maxprime(number)
    maximum = 0
    for i = 2, number - 1 do
        if(number % i == 0 and isprime(i)) then
            if(maximum < i) then
                maximum = i
            end
        end
    end
    return maximum end
end
```

It returns 0 everytime and the for loop seems to only run once. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the content of `isprime` and how you call `maxprime`? You need to provide a complete working example for us to see the issue (you have two `end` statements that produce syntax error, but other than that the code is valid).

Comment: Why there was end in here "return maximum end"? Also once again check your code for isprime() function, because it seems the for loop was working fine without isprime() function.

Comment: How do you know that the loop is only run once?

Comment: Assuming your `isprime()` works, why not just `function maxprime(number)
  for i = number, 1, -1 do
    if isprime(i) then return i end
  end
end
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that your `isPrime` function is returning `true` on prime numbers? You didn't post what your `isPrime` function is, so it's hard to tell if it's the culprit or not.

However, I will point out that you do not need to count up to `n-1`, and instead, as mentioned in comments by tonypdmtr, you can start with `n` and count down. It's actually better that way, as you'll return the first prime number that meets your criteria. See the code below:

```
function isPrime(n)
    for i = 2, n^(1/2) do
        if (n % i) == 0 then
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end

function maxPrime(n)
    for i = n, 2, -1 do
        if isPrime(i) and (n % i) == 0 then
            return i
        end
    end
end

> print(maxPrime(1449))
> 23
> print(maxPrime(7))
> 7
> print(maxPrime(13))
> 13
```

Hopefully this helps you, but if you have any questions, feel free to ask.